# getting pygame.Rect color without classes

Tags: python, pygame, rect, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to code Conway's game of life as a part of job qualification test,
using Python and ONLY PyGame library without classes
my approach to this is to create a grid of rectangles and assigning each rectangle to an 2d array
up to this point this approach is done, now as part of the game's rules i need to check the rectangles color, is there is a way to check a pygame.Rect object its color?

each rectangle created in this way:

```py
for y in range(0, WindowDimensions[1], CellSize):
    for x in range(0, WindowDimensions[0], CellSize):
        cell = pygame.Rect(x, y, CellSize, CellSize)
        AddCellToArray(cell)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface=Window, color=BLACK, rect=cell, width=1)
```

```py
Column, Row = 0, 0

def AddCellToArray(cell):
    nonlocal Column, Row
    if Row < len(BoardArr):
        if Column < len(BoardArr[0]):
            BoardArr[Row][Column] = cell
            Column += 1
        else:
            Row += 1
            Column = 0
            BoardArr[Row][Column] = cell
            Column += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object has no color. When you call [`pygame.draw.rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) the area on the screen defined by the rectangle is filled with the color.

Store the rectangle and its color in `BoardArr`:

```py
for y in range(0, WindowDimensions[1], CellSize):
    for x in range(0, WindowDimensions[0], CellSize):
        cell = pygame.Rect(x, y, CellSize, CellSize)
        color = BLACK
        AddCellToArray(cell, color)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface=Window, color=color, rect=cell, width=1)
```

```py
Column, Row = 0, 0

def AddCellToArray(cell, color):
    nonlocal Column, Row
    if Row < len(BoardArr):
        if Column < len(BoardArr[0]):
            BoardArr[Row][Column] = [cell, color]
            Column += 1
        else:
            Row += 1
            Column = 0
            BoardArr[Row][Column] = [cell, color]
            Column += 1
```

Comment: That's an excellent solution, i only changed the type of the pair to a list instead of a tuple, so i could change the contents later (mutable pair instead if immutable pair)

Comment: i know about classes, but sadly the assignment demands not using classes or external libraries